Receiving Null values from Eventhub streaming
I am new to PySpark, and facing an issue while consuming data from the Azure eventhub. I am unable to deserialize the consumed data. I see only null values upon deserializing data using the schema. Please find the below schema, eventhub message, and code that I am using to consume data and let me know how can I resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.
    #Sample Eventhub message:
    EventHubOverrideMessage(gtin13=00******0010, sourceId=0******5, lastUpdateTimestamp=2024-07-09T12:45:00.009805, lastUpdatedUser=null, inStore=ModalityOverride(reason=Other, override=true, startDate=2023-10-23T00:00, endDate=null), pickup=ModalityOverride(reason=Other, override=true, startDate=2023-10-23T00:00, endDate=null), delivery=ModalityOverride(reason=Other, override=true, startDate=2023-10-23T00:00, endDate=null), ship=null)


    # Deserialization Schema: (Tried replacingTimestampType with stringtype)
    StructType([
    StructField("gtin13", StringType(), True),
    StructField("sourceId", StringType(), True),
    StructField("lastUpdateTimestamp", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("lastUpdatedUser", StringType(), True),
    StructField("inStore", StructType([
    StructField("reason", StringType(), True),
    StructField("override", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("startDate", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("endDate", TimestampType(), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("pickup", StructType([
    StructField("reason", StringType(), True),
    StructField("override", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("startDate", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("endDate", TimestampType(), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("delivery", StructType([
    StructField("reason", StringType(), True),
    StructField("override", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("startDate", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("endDate", TimestampType(), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("ship", StructType([
    StructField("reason", StringType(), True),
    StructField("override", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("startDate", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("endDate", TimestampType(), True)
    ]), True)
    ])



    # Actual Schema:
    {
    "title": "schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
    "gtin13": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^[0-9]{13}$"
    },
    "sourceId": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^[0-9]{8}$"
    },
    "lastUpdateTimestamp": {
    "type": "string",
    "format": "date-time"
    },
    "inStore": {
    "type": [
    "object",
    "null"
    ],
    "properties": {
    "reason": {
    "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
    ]
    },
    "override": {
    "type": [
    "boolean",
    "null"
    ]
    },
    "startDate": {
    "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
    ],
    "format": "date-time"
    },
    "endDate": {
    "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
    ],
    "format": "date-time"
    }
    },
    "required": [
    "reason",
    "override",
    "startDate",
    "endDate"
    ]
    },
    "pickup": {
    "type": [
    "object",
    "null"
    ],
    "properties": {
    "reason": {
    "type": "string"
    },
    "override": {
    "type": [
    "boolean",
    "null"
    ]
    },
    "startDate": {
    "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
    ],
    "format": "date-time"
    },
    "endDate": {
    "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
    ],
    "format": "date-time"
    }
    },
    "required": [
    "reason",
    "override",
    "startDate",
    "endDate"
    ]
    },
    "delivery": {
    "type": [
    "object",
    "null"
    ],
    "properties": {
    "reason": {
    "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
    ]
    },
    "override": {
    "type": [
    "boolean",
    "null"
    ]
    },
    "startDate": {
    "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
    ],
    "format": "date-time"
    },
    "endDate": {
    "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
    ],
    "format": "date-time"
    }
    },
    "required": [
    "reason",
    "override",
    "startDate",
    "endDate"
    ]
    },
    "ship": {
    "type": [
    "object",
    "null"
    ],
    "properties": {
    "reason": {
    "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
    ]
    },
    "override": {
    "type": [
    "boolean",
    "null"
    ]
    },
    "startDate": {
    "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
    ],
    "format": "date-time"
    },
    "endDate": {
    "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
    ],
    "format": "date-time"
    }
    },
    "required": [
    "reason",
    "override",
    "startDate",
    "endDate"
    ]
    }
    },
    "required": [
    "gtin13",
    "sourceId",
    "lastUpdateTimestamp"
    ]
    }


    #CODE:
    kafkaDF = (
    spark.readStream.format("kafka")
    .option("subscribe", topic)
    .option(
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers",
    bootstrap_server,
    )
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config",EVENTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING)
    .option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", "60000")
    .option("kafka.session.timeout.ms", "30000")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
    .load()
    .withColumn("value", col("value").cast(StringType()))
    )

    print("Schema of Kafka DataFrame:")
    kafkaDF.printSchema()

    # Deserialize JSON data
    deserialized_stream = kafkaDF.withColumn(
    "data", F.from_json(col("value").cast("string"), json_schema)
    )
     
    parsed_df = deserialized_stream.select("data.*")

    # Display the parsed DataFrame
    display(deserialized_stream)


    # PRINT SCHEMA OUTPUT:
    Schema of Kafka DataFrame: root |-- key: binary (nullable = true) |-- value: string (nullable = true) |-- topic: string (nullable = true) |-- partition: integer (nullable = true) |-- offset: long (nullable = true) |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true) |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)

    # Deserialized Output:
    {"gtin13":null,"sourceId":null,"lastUpdateTimestamp":null,"inStore":null,"pickup":null,"delivery":null,"ship":null}


Did you tried inferSchema?
